# AngularJS JavaScript reading file from parent directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does anyone know how to get file from parent directory using `$http.get`?

The system works fine if I use `$http.get("customers.php")` (file customers.php produce json format data) where `customers.php` is in same directory but if I switch customer to parent directory, system doesn't work (using this expression `$http.get("../customers.php")` ).

I only use AngularJS.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Errors in console? Any request in the Network activity?

Comment: What if you pass the entire path?

Comment: try $http.get("./../customers.php") i think this will work. Did work for me. Basically ./ and then the path.

Comment: I try with ../customers.php but doesn't work. It doesn't work even with ./../customers.php or just with ../customers.php.

Comment: There is nothing in web console.

Answer (score 2):

Best practices will be provide complete URL.

Such As:

$http.get("http://example.com/customers.php")

Or you can use ../ instead of it.

Comment: Thank's for quick replay. But this doesn't work because the file is hidden from users, out of working directory. Do you have another solutions?

Comment: Doesn't matter that it was hidden or not. It only can send a http request to your customers.php file. If you are not clear provide some code.

Comment: I use https protocol and it works fine when file is in current directory. Like https://server.ip/customers.html

Comment: If I switch same file in parent directory, I get nothing in the browser and there is no error in the browser console.

Comment: Here I send you a code: <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("./../raspored_ispita_list.php")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});

</script>

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I make some mistake in customers.php file when I switch it to parent directory. Your answer was good and solutions work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that answer you get is not a solution for your problem. If it is true what you said, when file customers.php is not in the root of web directory, which means is hidden from url, then you can not solve problem with the help of $http.get function.
Suppose that we have

```
/var/www/public directory
```

and the file customers.php is in next directory

```
/var/customers.php
```

Your root directory of your web server is

```
/var/www/public
```

with your AngularJS files, like *.html or customers.html.

If someone enter this url

```
www.serverip.com
```

Your web server point to this directory 
`/var/www/public/customers.html`
and you want to read file from `/var/customers.php` with $http.get fuction.

You can not do that.

You must put customers.php in the root of your web server. For instance, in the next directory

```
/var/www/public/customers.php
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Thank you Arsenije. It was verry nice from you to explain how $http.get function works. Thanks again.